# Is it possible to display nested command with git log --pretty

Tags: git, git-log

I came up with a one liner command to display the names, SHA-1 hashes and URLs of each submodule:

```
git submodule foreach --quiet "echo $name:$sha1: `git config --get remote.origin.url`/tree/$sha1"
```

I want to display the hash and URL of head as well, but struggling to figure out which format command should I use. I have tried:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"`git config --get remote.origin.url`/tree/%h"
```

but it doesn't evaluate the `git config --get remote.origin.url` part and instead prints it verbatim. Can we someone format with nested command? Or is there any other `git` command which can produce the desired output (origin.url + "/tree/" + "sha1")?

It would be much appreciated if the solution is one liner with single, pure git command executing the nested command as I need to run it on a slim Windows build environment, where python, ruby and bash etc. commands (like `cut` etc.) are note available.

Comment: I make a test with `git log -1 --pretty=format:"`git config --get remote.origin.url`/tree/%h"` in a repo and it prints `https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/repo-hooks/tree/325c0fd`. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: On Windows Command Prompt, it produces `git config --get remote.origin.url/tree/`. The first command I wrote was purely git interpreter doing the magic (as the backtick support is clearly mentioned in git-scm docs), but for `--pretty=tformat` etc. the docs only has fixed number of specifier without mentioning anything about subcommand. I guess in your case, Unix shell might have assisted the interpretation of subcommand, if that's the case.

Comment: I see. I thought it was git-bash on windows. Try `for /f %i in ('git config --get remote.origin.url') do git log -1 --pretty=format:%i/tree/%h`. But still not perfect. It seems cmd can't work as well as shell in this case.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks a lot! I dressed it up a bit to be able to make it run as an MSBuild task with escaping perks that works cross-platform and collects the output in `.myhashes` file in a desired format: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15081c5533ec86ac34a4f74be57caac5 (`dotnet msbuild GitHash-task.proj`). Could you add your solution an answer so I can accept? :)